# Opening another VF page from Lightning Experience 's VF Page

Tags: lightning, slds

We have migrated a VF page from Classic to Lightning and it is working fine.

In this page, we need to open another page on a click of a link. So, we have written code as below :

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/Test_Page?id={!MyObj.Id}&SelectedRecordType='ABC'" target="_blank" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Open New VF Page</apex:outputLink>
```

The page we are opening (Test_Page), has also SLDS applied and shows properly.
It works fine in both modes (classic and lightning).

Can someone suggest, is it a preferable approach to open another VF page by using `<apex:outputLink>` in Lightning mode?